# send image to the server from iPhone and store it on the server using restful

Tags: java, iphone, rest, upload

I create an iPhone application where the use should subscribe before using it.
While subscribing he should add his picture from the galerie,
My problem is how to send that picture to the server side via a POST methode, I'm using restful webservices, and after recuperate it from the server side how can I store it on the server.

Any help would be very appreciated 
Thank you a lot in advence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NSMutableURLRequest` you can upload image to server

```
-(void)uploadImage
{
    NSString *strURL =@"your server url";// Url server
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *file1Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"];
    // NSData *file1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile];

    //Create web Service
    // NSString *urlString = @”http://demos.nanostuffs.com/iphone/audio.php”;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1Data]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
}
```

Comment: thank a lot, I tried this, still how to recuperate this image from the server side, which form of data will be send to the server and how can I store it on my server

Comment: which type script use at server?? .net or php?

Comment: i'm using Java, with restful webservices

Comment: http://activehigh.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/uploading-files-from-iphone-to-asp-net-web-site/ take a look

Comment: yes this is useful from the iphone side, but from the server side he use .net, and i use java so i didn't understand anything from him :(

Comment: http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java-tutorial/java-jdbc/how-to-write-image-into-mysql-database-using-java

Comment: http://rkj2me.blogspot.in/2011/07/java-code-to-store-and-retrieve-image.html you can check

Comment: thank you Wild Tiger for your answers, but i just don't want to store the image in the database, i want to store it in a folder on my server and store just its link into the database, but thank you anyway for your help