# Trying to save a uiimageview image into a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to save the contents of `UIImageView` into a variable that I can send to a server.

The contents of `UIImageView` is selected by the user from their camera role.

I cant seem to actually store the binary data / other format to send, how can I achieve this? Everything I have found on the net is saving the image into main memory which isnt what I want.

Edit:

Here is the actual image selection:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: How are you converting the UIImage to NSData?

Comment: @Jonathan I havent done that, maybe that is what I need? Just edited my question with the code that selects the image, which is where I imagine I would store the data into a variable / property.

Comment: I don't have any experience storing images on a server, but I have read that you can convert the image to an NSData object and store that on the server. This answer may help you or atleast lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895311/send-image-to-the-server-from-iphone-and-store-it-on-the-server-using-restful

Comment: No problem man. Don't forget that you will also have to have some script on the server to process and store the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send image to server. The only way to send it is by converting the `UIImage` to `NSData` .

> ```
> NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0);
>
> NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
> ```